# Вопрос по парсингу JSON

Tags: json, парсер, swift

Подскажите, в JSON'e данные приходят в виде:

name: Afghanistan

languages: Pashto, Uzbek, Turkmen

При запуске, в поле cell.countryLanguage.text выводится только первый язык Pashto. Как мне связать, чтобы у Afghanistan было три языка — Pashto, Uzbek, Turkmen?

Код я сократил намного, постарался оставить самую суть.

```
    struct CountryElement: Codable {
        let name: String
        let languages: [Language]
     }
    
    struct Language: Codable {
        let iso6391: String?
        let iso6392: String
        let name: String
        let nativeName: String?
    }
    
    var name = [String]()
    var languages = [Language]()
    
    struct CountryStruct {
        var name: String
        var languages: Language
    }
    
    
    func getData(_ completion: @escaping() -> Void, JSONerrorAlertCallBack: @escaping() -> Void, serverErrorCallBack: @escaping() -> Void) {
        let urlString = "https://restcountries.com/v2/all"
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.ephemeral
        let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration)
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            return
        }
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            guard error == nil else { return }
            do {
                let countryInfo = try JSONDecoder().decode([CountryElement].self, from: data)
                
                for index in 0..<countryInfo.count {
                    name.append(countryInfo[index].name)
                    languages.append(contentsOf: countryInfo[index].languages)
                }
            } catch let error {
                  print(error)
     
            }
            completion()
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    
    final class Countries {
        func sortArrays(JSONerrorAlertCallBack: @escaping() -> Void) -> [CountryStruct] {
            var sortedCountries = [CountryStruct]()
            for index in 0..<name.count {
                sortedCountries.append(CountryStruct(name: name[index], languages: languages[index]))
            }
            return sortedCountries
        }
    }

 cell.countryName.text = allcountries[indexPath.row].name
 cell.countryLanguage.text = allcountries[indexPath.row].languages.name
```

[{"name":"Afghanistan","topLevelDomain":[".af"],"alpha2Code":"AF","alpha3Code":"AFG","callingCodes":["93"],"capital":"Kabul","altSpellings":["AF","Afġānistān"],"region":"Southern Asia","continent":"Asia","population":27657145,"latlng":[33.0,65.0],"demonym":"Afghan","area":652230.0,"gini":29.4,"timezones":["UTC+04:30"],"borders":["IRN","PAK","TKM","UZB","TJK","CHN"],"nativeName":"افغانستان","numericCode":"004","currencies":[{"code":"AFN","name":"Afghan afghani","symbol":"؋"}],"languages":[{"iso639_1":"ps","iso639_2":"pus","name":"Pashto","nativeName":"پښتو"},{"iso639_1":"uz","iso639_2":"uzb","name":"Uzbek","nativeName":"Oʻzbek"},{"iso639_1":"tk","iso639_2":"tuk","name":"Turkmen","nativeName":"Türkmen"}],"translations":{"br":"Afeganistão","pt":"Afeganistão","nl":"Afghanistan","hr":"Afganistan","fa":"افغانستان","de":"Afghanistan","es":"Afganistán","fr":"Afghanistan","ja":"アフガニスタン","it":"Afghanistan","hu":"Afganisztán"},"flags":["https://restcountries.com/data/afg.svg","https://restcountries.com/data/png/afg.png"],"regionalBlocs":[{"acronym":"SAARC","name":"South Asian Association for Regional Cooperation"}],"cioc":"AFG","independent":true}]

Comment: джейсончик прикрепите в виде текста

Comment: Прикрепил, он конечно урезанный до одной страны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте вот так внутри getData:

```
for index in 0..<countryInfo.count {
    for language in 0..<countryInfo[index].languages.count {
        name.append(countryInfo[index].name)
        languages.append(countryInfo[index].languages[language])
    }
}
```

Это вам поможет, но в этом случае у вас будет столько записей стран, сколько языков, что не очень эффективно. На самом деле, вам достаточно всё парсить в один массив CountryElement и брать данные сразу из него, а CountryStruct, name и languages не нужны.

Comment: Все разобрался. Я зачем-то создал еще одну структуру CountryStruct и в нее загонял. ))

Answer (score 1):

Так у вас же структура страны содержит только один язык

```
struct CountryStruct {
        var name: String
        var languages: Language
    }
```

И заполняете вы ее только с одним языком

```
CountryStruct(name: name[index], languages: languages[index])
```

Поменяйте на массив как у `CountryElement`, либо создавайте их столько, сколько языков в стране.
Сейчас, насколько можно понять из приведенного кода, у вас создается одна структура на страну.

Comment: Нет, не одна структура на страну, в структуре все 248 стран.